# Virtualbox: прочитать файл, хранящийся на гостевой машине

Tags: virtualbox

Внутри Virtualbox работает windows приложение, которое пишет свой журнал в файл, допустим `C:\Users\user\Documents\app.txt`. Я хочу со свой хост-системы Linux читать этот файл. Как это сделать?

- Гость: Windows-10, хост: Ubuntu
- Настроить местоположение журнала невозможно
- Вариант пробросить общую папку - не работает, так как каталог монтируется в виде диска

Comment: У virtualbox есть api,  через него не выходит?  https://github.com/sethmlarson/virtualbox-python